# Замена значений по ключ-таблицы (R)

Tags: r

Есть DF, в котором есть столбец А. Он состоит и пустых, числовых и текстовых значений.
[image: DF]

Еще есть ключ-таблицы. В которой описано "на какое значение надо заменить значения из DF$A". Т.е. Надо найти в DF$A все не числовые значения и заменить их на значения указанные в ключ-таблице.

[image: таблица]

Вопрос: как это сделать?
И можно ли без циклов, только по адресации ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы делал так:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("a,b
         37,z
         24,x
         42,y
         ,o")

keys <- read_csv("a,c
                 37,Z
                 42,Y
                 ,O")

df %>% 
  full_join(keys) %>% 
  mutate(a = ifelse(is.na(c), a, c))
```

Но есть и варианты с базовым R.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на функцию `dplyr::recode()` из dplyr.

Пример из справки:

```r
char_vec <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE)
recode(char_vec, a = "Apple")
recode(char_vec, a = "Apple", b = "Banana")
```